# nginx virtual hosting for default domain not working

Tags: nginx

I am trying to setup server name based nginx. I have one domain with three sub domain.

For example

> suyashjain.com

is my main domain, for which I am having one wordpress.

> www.suyashjain.com

is also there , which is same as non www domain.

> wordpress.suyashjain.com

is another sub domain , again another wordpress is hosted.

Now I have made the following config.

```
 server {
        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        root /var/www/html/wordpress;
        index index.php;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name suyashjain.com www.suyashjain.com;
}
 server {
        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        root /var/www/html/wordpress2;
        index index.php;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name wordpress.suyashjain.com;
}
```

When I am restarting the nginx , I am getting the following warning.

> conflicting server name "suyashjain.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored

and getting 404 Not Found while trying suyashjain.com or www.suyashjain.com on browser. As www is going to suyashjain.com only.

Comment: Start with your `nginx.conf` file and check each file that is `include`d into it. Look for including the same file twice or old files or backup files which may cause a duplicate `server` block.

Comment: thanks, stupid error...i knew this could be the issue ...but did not check